# Convert varchar to datetime(127) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 2 columns: `endReportDate (varchar)`, `reportType (varchar)`

```
endReportDate(varchar), reportType(varchar)
-------------------------------------------    
2018-10-09T16:01Z         FEDEX
```

I need select this data in '2018-08-07T16:01:30' format.

I am trying it like this:

```
select convert(Datetime, endDateReport, 127) from table
```

but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Why you store `DATETIME` as `VARCHAR`? Why?

Comment: The simple answer is: No, you can't because there is no `DATETIME` 127

Comment: That's not a format supported by SQL Server. You'd have to do some string manipulation first. (E.g. `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF('2018-10-09T16:01Z', 17, 0, ':00'), 127)`.)

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you're storing date and time values are a `varchar`. **Always** store your data in a datatype representative of it; `varchar` is not a "one size fits all" datatype.

The best solution, therefore, is to fix your design. Assuming that **all** your data has the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mmZ` then you could do the following:

```
--UPDATE values to be a valid datetime String
UPDATE YourTable
SET endReportDate = REPLACE(endReportDate,'Z','') + ':00';
GO
--Chnage the data type
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN endReportDate datetime2(0);
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

> I need select this data in '2018-08-07T16:01:30' format.

So remove `'Z'` like

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(45) = '2018-10-09T16:01Z';

SELECT REPLACE(@Str, 'Z', ':30') Result
```

Or even

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(@Str, 'Z', ':30'), 127) Result
```

Comment: With apologies, I kind of stole your answer but used zero seconds, as I think it's misleading to make up a non-zero number of seconds when the source data didn't have that precision, regardless of the fact that the questioner asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the questioner has no control over the table structure and wants a select query that outputs a string in the required format and is stuck in SQL Server 2008, one answer would be:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(endDateReport,'Z',':00')
FROM theTable
```

Here we are replacing the `Z` with `:00` as it appears the original data only has a precision of a minute and yet the output is requested to have seconds precision.

If the intent was to end up with a `datetime` datatype, then the answer would be:

```sql
SELECT 
  CONVERT(
    datetime,
    REPLACE(endDateReport,'Z',':00'),
    127)
FROM theTable
```

We still have to add the seconds here because there's no style code that accepts only minutes precision. 127 is the closest, and requires seconds.

In SQL Server 2016 and up we have the addition of `PARSE` and `FORMAT` functions, with `PARSE` being ISO 8601 aware:

```sql
FORMAT(
  PARSE('2023-08-15T10:01Z' AS datetimeoffset),
  'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
);
```

will output `2023-08-15T10:01:00`.

To put it in the context of the table in the question, a select statement could be:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(
    PARSE(endDateReport AS datetimeoffset),
    'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
  ) FROM theTable
```

or just to convert the data into a `datetimeoffset` type, which would correctly preserve the fact that the original times are UTC (which is otherwise not apparent in the `datetime` type), we would just have

```sql
SELECT PARSE(endDateReport AS datetimeoffset)
  FROM theTable
```